# Attempting to troubleshoot copy constructor crash issue

Tags: c++

I've been attempting to troubleshoot this code with no avail. It crashed just as I call the copy constructor. In other attempts at calling the copy constructor the output of the new object has been random characters.

I have a feeling that my lack of understanding of memory management carries over to overloading the `=` operator too.

Here is my copy constructor....

```
MyString::MyString(const MyString& obj) 
{
    delete [] str;
    int temp=obj.len;

    len =   temp;

    str = new char[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {    
        char temp=obj.str[i];

        str[i] = temp;
    }
}
```

Here is my overloaded `=` ....

```
MyString& MyString::operator=(const MyString& obj)
{
    delete [] str;
    int temp = obj.len;

    len = temp;    
    str = new char[len];

    for ( int i = 0; i<=len; i++)
    {    
        char temp = obj.str[i];
        str[i] =  temp;
    }
    str[len] = '\0';

    return *this;
}
```

in the main method I call the copy constructor like so...

```
MyString stt3(str2); //str2 already exists.
```

Can anyone suggest where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Check before deleting memory whether it is allocated or not.

Comment: apart from the main issue (which R Sahu points out), the copy-constructor forgets about null-termination; and in both cases you did not allocate space for the null terminator.

Comment: @a_pradhan there is no way to check that

Comment: I'm guessing all those `temp` variables are for debugging? If not they can be safely removed and the assignment done directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
delete [] str;
```

in the copy constructor is not right. `str` is not initialized before that line. Removing that line should help, if not remove all the problems.

Also, you probably need to allocate one more object than `len` and null terminate `str`.

```
  str = new char[len+1];  // Need +1

  ...

  str[len] '\0';
```

You also need to change the call to `new char[]` in the assignment operator function too. You need:

```
  str = new char[len+1];
```

Comment: I have tried the above but still getting a bad memory allocation flag when debugging. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Serge, the call to `new char[]` has to be changed the assignment operator function too. I that doesn't fix all your problems, I suggest creating a new post with a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't understand what it means: new char[] has to be changed the assignment operator function too.

Comment: @Serge, you are using `str = new char[len];` in the `operator=` function. That needs to be changed to `str = new char[len+1];`

Comment: Oh, understood. I've tried and it does not change the issue. My thinking was that since the len variable starts from 1 but the cstring indexing starts from 0 there would be enough room in the array for the null pointer. Thanks again.

Comment: str[len] **=**  '\0';